# How can I know that one class is a subclass of another one?

Tags: qooxdoo

```
qx.Class.define("A")

qx.Class.define("B",
   extend: A
)
```

I'd like to know that B is a subclass of A. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at [the API of qx.Class](http://demo.qooxdoo.org/current/apiviewer/#qx.Class). It has a stastic method `isSubClassOf()` - I think that's exactly what you want.